# How to substitute a complex number in a complex function?

Tags: complex-numbers

I know for the regular cases, but what I am after is something like this:

$\lim\limits_{z \to 1+5i} ix+y$

is it: i(1) + (5i) = **6i**, or: i(1) + 5 = **5+i**
?!

Comment: Usually, we take $z=x+iy \to z=1+5i \to x=1 , y= 5$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We usually define $z=x+yi$ so $x,\,y\in\Bbb R$, making the answer $5+i$.